# How to get access to the Websphere 6.1 ant tasks from vanilla ant (not ws_ant)

Tags: ant, websphere, task, websphere-6.1

I guess I need to know what I need in the classpath (what jar) in order to execute WebSphere 6.1 ant tasks. If someone can provide an example that would be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Websphere 6.1, you can use the jar com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar to access the ant tasks.

On Windows, the jar is located in the plugins directory (for me this is: C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins).

Answer (score 4):

The Actual Websphere Ant tasks are defined in `wsanttasks.jar`.

A possible path for linux Systems is `/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/wsanttasks.jar`

However I doubt that you will be successfull just by including that, as I do remember trying it once and it failed because of dependecies.

However, it is not impossible to do it as `ws_ant` is just a wrapper script which adds *all the required classpaths and calls the inbuilt ant*. So if you have time to look into the `ws_ant` script you will be able to get all the required classpath's.

By the way is there any special reason why you want to avoid `ws_ant`, that will surely make your life simple.

Comment: Possible scenario: you want to build and deploy but you don't want to install WAS on the build machine - say its a jenkins node for example.

Answer (score 0):

websphere's ant tasks are screwed up and they invoke wsadmin.bat

you can do that yourself